# Mix wont connect to nodes: Error status 0

Tags: testnets, mix, morden, connections

I managed to configure Morden test network to run, but Mix is unable to discover testnet node, it is giving this error:

A "Unable to initiate request to the live network. Please verify your ethereum node is up. Error status: 0"

Any help?

Comment: maybe i need to wait until blockchain will sync fully..

Comment: If you found a solution, it's totally okay to [answer your own question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). This will help users in the future who may face the same problems.

Comment: Already synced, but still gives errors:

Comment: @5chdn is right, If you found a solution, it's totally okay to answer your own question.